# Why is it necessary to add locally attached printers?

Tags: printing

I seldom have to print anything on paper anymore, so my knowledge about printers is really limited. Last weekend, I demoed Oneiric to my father, who still prints stuff, and even though his printer is attached using USB, I had to select the printer from a list. Why is that? I mean, if I attach a memory stick, I don't have to select it. It just works. Why is that no so with printers? For network printers, I understand why they have to be added, since a company can have thousands of printers when one user only needs to use a couple of them. But shouldn't directly connected printers just work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/printing/C/printing.html), things are supposed to happen exactly as you expect:

> Plug your printer into your computer and power it on. Most printers
>   will automatically be detected an configured. Once detected, a printer
>   icon will appear in the notification area and after waiting a few
>   moments, you should get a popup with the text "Printer is ready for
>   printing.

Unfortunately, setting up a printer may be more difficult than mounting a flash drive, so sometimes auto-detection fails. In this case you need to add the printer manually.

Answer (score -1):

You could always print to a file instead, or tell the system to use  a printer in the network, which isn't automatically seen.

And since Linux evolved from a networking-server-system, having multiple printers available was very common for Unix systems.